# Selenium handling duplicate xpaths of same type in java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, cucumber

I am trying to dynamically select items from a drop down menu based on input. This isn't really a problem unless values share a name. For instance if this is my Cucumber statement

```
 When I go to the "Inventory" / "Inventory" application
```

When I call this method:

```
@When("^I go to the \"([^\"]*)\" / \"([^\"]*)\" application$")
public void i_go_to_the_application(String hoverMenu, String subMenuName) throws Throwable {
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.linkText(hoverMenu));
    actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    WebElement submenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[.='" + subMenuName + "']"));

    actions.moveToElement(submenu);
    actions.click().perform();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
```

My test crash because it cannot find the subMenuElement. This code works swimmingly if the menu names are different such as Inventory > Items.

Now I've already checked this question
[Selenium: handling multiple inputs with same xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272500/selenium-handling-multiple-inputs-with-same-xpath)

However the solution provide doesn't seem to be helpful since both elements are in the drop down menu with one being a submenu to that one: Inventory > Inventory

I ran this through the selenium IDE and no matter how many ways I've tried to "find" the Inventory element it only ever finds one item. Since the user of my tests can select any number of items from a drop down menu and then subsequent submenus, I can't rely on IDs. Is there a way to select the first menu item for sure and then select the submenu item.

Comment: Could you share HTML for this Menu and submemu as well

Answer (score 1):

Change this from a partial link text to a xpath search

```
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.linkText(hoverMenu));
```

to below

```
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement("//a[.='" + hoverMenu + "']");
```

You just need the 2 xpaths to be different so even if the names are same you will get your result.

Comment: I've tried this approach, both times they find the same element. I've used a slight work around where I scan for the elements ID and then use a !comparison to find the other element.

Answer (score 0):

It seems submemu `Inventory` element existing inside main menu `Inventory` element. Then you should try to find submemu element on the main menu context as below :-

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.linkText(hoverMenu));
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink);

WebElement submenu = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy(menuHoverLink, By.xpath(".//span[.='" + subMenuName + "']")))

actions.moveToElement(submenu);
actions.click().perform();
```

Comment: This still returns the top level item.

Comment: Tried once as `menuHoverLink.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[.='" + subMenuName + "']"));` and let me know..